# UITableView Of YouTube Videos Actively Fetched From A YouTube Playlist

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, youtube, ios6

I have been searching for about 2 years now and I can't seem to come across a viable solution. I have learned how to embed youtube videos via a UIWebView, howeever this case is not usable if someone wanted to have a dynamic UITableView That actively fetched youtube videos from a given playlist. Does anypne know how to this or could someone point me in the right directionas per how to figure this out?